# Python - Summing a list of dictionaries with a condition

Tags: python, dictionary, sum, conditional-statements

Let say I have a list:

```
l = [{"num1":3, "num2":8, "num3":5, "type":"A"}, {"num1":2, "num2":5, "num3":5, "type":"B"}, {"num1":5, "num2":2, "num3":1, "type":"A"}, {"num1":4, "num2":4, "num3":9, "type":"B"}
```

and I want to create 2 dictionaries:
sumA:

```
{"num1":8, "num2":10, "num3":6}
```

sumB:

```
{"num1":6, "num2":9, "num3":14}
```

I want to make it simple and readable as much as possible.
I managed to do it in a horrible way using too many variables...

Thanks!

Comment: are there always 4 dictionaries in the list and are there always only 3 nubmers in each of them?

Comment: "I managed to do it in a horrible way using too many variables..." Then why don't you paste that code here?

Comment: @lonut Hulub - the number is always the same (4 and 3 are just examples)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done reasonably easily using some [list and dict comprehensions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw).

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

l = [{"num1": 3, "num2": 8, "num3": 5, "type": "A"},
     {"num1": 2, "num2": 5, "num3": 5, "type": "B"},
     {"num1": 5, "num2": 2, "num3": 1, "type": "A"},
     {"num1": 4, "num2": 4, "num3": 9, "type": "B"}]

wanted_values = {"num1", "num2", "num3"}

type_getter = itemgetter("type")
groups = [(group, list(items)) for group, items in 
          groupby(sorted(l, key=type_getter), type_getter)]

print({group: {k: sum(map(itemgetter(k), items)) for k in wanted_values}
       for group, items in groups})
```

Which gives us:

```
{'B': {'num2': 9, 'num3': 14, 'num1': 6}, 
 'A': {'num2': 10, 'num3': 6, 'num1': 8}}
```

We sort the values by type, then split them into groups with [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) (making the items lists instead of generators, as we need to iterate over them multiple times).

We then use a nested dict comprehension to create the data we need, summing the values from the items and assigning them to a group.

This is a flexible solution that would scale to having more than just two types.

Comment: Did you run this code? I get a TypeError while trying to run it.

Comment: @segfolt I (accidentally) ran this in 2.x - it appears to not work in 3.x, let me work that one out.

Comment: @gilgil28 This version should work in 2.x and 3.x happily, with float values if needs be.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a nested comprehension.

```
lst = [{"num1": 3, "num2": 8, "num3": 5, "type": "A"},
     {"num1": 2, "num2": 5, "num3": 5, "type": "B"},
     {"num1": 5, "num2": 2, "num3": 1, "type": "A"},
     {"num1": 4, "num2": 4, "num3": 9, "type": "B"}]

sum_by_a = {key: sum(d[key] for d in lst if d['type'] == 'A')
    for key in ("num1", "num2", "num3")}
```

or, for a generic type,

```
sum_by_type = lambda t: {
    key: sum(d[key] for d in lst if d['type'] == t)
        for key in ("num1", "num2", "num3")}

 sum_by_b = sum_by_type(B)
```

Comment: @gilgil28: Pick me! Pick me! No cheap imports, 100% locally made!

Comment: `lambda` is simple a way to make simple functions inline - it's completely inappropriate here, in my opinion, as a `def` would do the same job more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I would go that way, using [`Collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce

l = [{"num1":3, "num2":8, "num3":5, "type":"A"},
     {"num1":2, "num2":5, "num3":5, "type":"B"},
     {"num1":5, "num2":2, "num3":1, "type":"A"},
     {"num1":4, "num2":4, "num3":9, "type":"B"}]

def remove_keys(d, keys):
    return {i: j for i, j in d.items() if i not in keys}

def add_dicts(dicts):
    return reduce(lambda a, b: a+b,  map(Counter, dicts))

tmp = {}
for d in l:
    tmp[d["type"]] = tmp.get(d["type"], []) + [remove_keys(d, ["type"])]

result = {key: add_dicts(value) for key, value in dict(tmp).items()}
```

which gives:

```
{'A': Counter({'num2': 10, 'num1': 8, 'num3': 6}), 
'B': Counter({'num3': 14, 'num2': 9, 'num1': 6})}
```